# How can i simply merge csv files together with fme

Tags: csv, fme-form

I have some csv files which have varying contents. I want to simply disregard the schema and write the lines of text into one file. Which transformers or technique could I use to achieve this?

Comment: I have done this in windows and mac on the command line - very easy.http://www.wikihow.com/Merge-Text-(.Txt)-Files-in-Command-Prompt

Comment: I would like to keep it within my fme model.

Comment: You can merge csv here: [merge csv files](http://merge-csv.com )

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP wants to do this with FME not an online resource.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/103825)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/103825)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to treat the CSV files as just being text files, then use a `text reader` to read them (simplest to just use a single dynamic version rather than separate feature readers). The files will be read in and treated just as though they're a normal text file; schema will be ignored.

You can write them out into one single file using a single `text writer`. The entire workspace should only consist of those two transformers (one dynamic text reader, one text writer).